# Why does jQuery addClass not work on div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript method that has 2 parameters, the first is the ID of a tr element, the other is an actual div.  My add/remove class jQuery method works fine for the first item (which I get with a jQuery selector).  However it throws a javascript error when I use it on the passed in Div.

```
onclick="ToggleTicketDetails('ticketDetails_@(ticket.TicketID)', this);"
```

I can obviously use a jQuery selector on the div to fix this, however I would like to know why it behaves this way.

```
function ToggleTicketDetails(detailsId, divSender) {
    //alert(divSender);
    var element = $('#' + detailsId);
    //alert(element);
    if (element.hasClass("TicketDetailsOff")) { 
        element.removeClass("TicketDetailsOff").addClass("TicketDetailsOn");
        divSender.removeClass("DivAsExpand").addClass("DivAsCollapse");
    }
    else { 
        element.removeClass("TicketDetailsOn").addClass("TicketDetailsOff");
        divSender.removeClass("DivAsCollapse").addClass("DivAsExpand");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`divSender` is DOM element. Use `jquery` object `$(divSender)` to apply `removeClass` and `addClass` on this like below.

```
function ToggleTicketDetails(detailsId, divSender) {
    var element = $('#' + detailsId);

    if (element.hasClass("TicketDetailsOff")) { 
        element.removeClass("TicketDetailsOff").addClass("TicketDetailsOn");
        $(divSender).removeClass("DivAsExpand").addClass("DivAsCollapse");
    }
    else { 
        element.removeClass("TicketDetailsOn").addClass("TicketDetailsOff");
        $(divSender).removeClass("DivAsCollapse").addClass("DivAsExpand");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, by implication jQuery extentions (like removeClass and addClass) do not work on DOM elements, but only objects?